# Dailymotion video recommendation

Tags: html, video, html5-video, dailymotion-api, video-embedding

Hello I am making a website and I have to put some videos on my website. I have uploaded the videos to daily-motion website and I have successfully linked them to my website. however after you watch the videos it recommends different videos to you so you can watch another video when the original video is finished.
It looks like something like this:[image]

is there way that I can make it stop suggesting videos to me, so when you finish the original video it just asks you to watch it again, instead of giving video suggestions, is there any other website beside YOUTUBE VIMEO and daily motion that I can upload my videos to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how to stop dailymotion from suggesting other videos, but in terms of alternatives to youtube, vimeo and dailymotion, you could try http://mediacrush.net/ or [public instances of mediagoblin](https://wiki.mediagoblin.org/Live_instances).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can hide related videos at the end: set the player parameter `related` to 0 when you embed the player.

Check https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#player-parameters